# openejb.xml configuration file in tomee server

Tags: openjpa, apache-tomee, openejb

I'm using TomEE 1.5.2 server and I would like to know where I can find `openejb.xml` file?

I have to configure this file, like there:
http://tomee.apache.org/openjpa.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only `openejb.xml` in OpenEJB standalone. In TomEE, it is `tomee.xml`, found in the `conf` directory.